# Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object?

Tags: angularjs

How fix Error:

> [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response
>   to contain an array but got an object?

// Service

```
   angular.module('admin.services', ['ngResource'])       
    // GET TASK LIST ACTIVITY
    .factory('getTaskService', function($resource) {
        return $resource('../rest/api.php?method=getTask&q=*',{ 'get':    {method:'GET'}});
    })
```

// Controller

```
$scope.getTask = getTaskService.query(function (response) {
    angular.forEach(response, function (item) {
        if (item.numFound > 0) {
            for(var i = 0; i < item.numFound; i++) {

                $scope.getTasks[i] = item.docs[i];

            }

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First of all you should configure `$resource` in different manner: without query params in the URL. Default query parameters may be passed as properties of the second parameter in `resource(url, paramDefaults, actions)`. It is also to be mentioned that you configure `get` method of resource and using `query` instead.

**Service**

```
angular.module('admin.services', ['ngResource'])       
  // GET TASK LIST ACTIVITY
  .factory('getTaskService', function($resource) {
    return $resource(
      '../rest/api.php',
      { method: 'getTask', q: '*' }, // Query parameters
      {'query': { method: 'GET' }}
    );
  })
```

**Documentation**

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

Answer (score 171):

Also, if your service is sending an object instead of an array add **isArray:false** to its declaration.

```
'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false }
```

Comment: It's not working for me. Only the startpage ("You created a service...) will be save when changing isArray to false.

Answer (score 109):

```
$resource("../rest/api"}).get();
```

returns an object.

```
$resource("../rest/api").query();
```

returns an array.

You must use :

```
return $resource('../rest/api.php?method=getTask&q=*').query();
```

Comment: from the error message itself it was pretty hard to see that I have use a different method.

Comment: I added a quote to the url in the answer. If this is not the correct place for it please edit.

Answer (score 20):

In order to handle arrays with the $resource service, it's suggested that you use the query method. As you can see below, the query method is built to handle arrays.

```
    { 'get':    {method:'GET'},
      'save':   {method:'POST'},
      'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
      'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
      'delete': {method:'DELETE'} 
   };
```

User `$resource("apiUrl").query();`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are sending the proper parameters too. This happened to me after switching to UI-Router.

To fix it, I changed $routeParams to use $stateParams in my controller. The main issue was that $stateParams was no longer sending a proper parameter to the resource.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here in 2021, another way this request may look is as follows (at least it was in our app)

```
angular.module('load').factory('StateService', ['$resource', 'store', function($resource, store) {
    return $resource('/some/url', {}, {
        fetchAllStateCodes: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,  // Response is an array of objects
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + store.get("jwt"),
                "Content-type": "application/json"
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

From all of the good answers, it still wasn't obvious to me as to where to put the `isArray` flag...