# Expected response to contain an array but got an object - Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular, I am sending a JSON object from webapi and doing it like this in Angular:

```
 getInfo: function (Num) {

            return $resource("services/api/GetInfo/GetByNum?Num=" + Num).query({}, isArray=false);

        }
```

but I am keep getting this error:

**Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object**

I've already set the isArray=false, am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041306/angular-js-how-fix-error-resourcebadcfg-error-in-resource-configuration-e

Comment: Try `.query({},{isArray:false});` or `.query({isArray:false});`

Comment: getting the same error.