# Angular Js. How fix Error: $resource:badcfg Response does not match configured parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get data from json file by using $resources, but I always get that error.
However, I am able to do it with $http, thus I believe something wrong with my service setup.

Here is my controller:

```
$scope.serviceRes = serviceRes.get({fileName: 'services.json'}, function(svcs) {

});
```

and here is my service

```
angular.module('myservices', ['ngResource'])
  .factory('serviceRes', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource(':fileName', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{fileName:'services.json'}, isArray:false}
    });
  }]);
```

note: I already tried to use `isArray:true` as well, but it is still not working.

and here is the error explanation from https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg?p0=array:

*This error occurs when the $resource service expects a response that can be deserialized as an array, receives an object, or vice versa. By default, all resource actions expect objects, except query which expects arrays.
To resolve this error, make sure your $resource configuration matches the actual format of the data returned from the server.*

But unfortunately I still have no idea how to fix it. I already look similar thread, [Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041306/angular-js-how-fix-error-resourcebadcfg-error-in-resource-configuration-e), but still could not solve it.
Any help?

**edit:**

here is the json file

```
[
    {"name": "aaaa",
     "time": "3.00 PM",
     "desc": "Description 1",
     "cp": "John (0004 123 456)",
     "email":"email@email.com"},
    {"name": "bbbbb",
     "time": "12.00 PM",
     "desc": "Description 2",
     "cp": "John Doe (0414 141 414)",
     "email":"email2@yahoo.com"}
]
```

Comment: Is the response really an Array? It might help to include the contents of `services.json`.

Comment: I have added the json file

Comment: [Here a solution that worked for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26093452/6553190)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `serviceRes.get(...)` method, put `serviceRes.query(...)`, while keeping the original parameters without any change, this results into the following statement:

```
$scope.serviceRes = serviceRes.query({fileName: 'services.json'}, function(svcs) {

});
```

As the [$resource documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) says (look at the "return" section): the `query()` method is the only one that pre-sets the value of `isArray` to `true`, in my opinion - this means that `query` is the guaranteed function to return an array within the response.

Comment: Please add more details to your answer. Check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7693/218121) about writing a good answer