# Response does not match configured parameter:

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am getting following error in angular $resource:
[error description](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg?p0=array&p1=object)

```
Error: error:badcfg
Response does not match configured parameter:
Error in resource configuration for action `array`. Expected response to contain an object but got an {2}
```

I initialized the ng app as follows:

```
var appRoot = angular.module('smapp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource']);
```

The service:

```
appRoot.factory('ProgramsResource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('Home/Program', {}, { Program: { method: 'get', isArray: false } })
});
```

In my controller:

```
appRoot.controller('ProgramCtrl', function ($scope, ProgramsResource) {
    $scope.searchPrograms = function () {
        $scope.Programs = ProgramsResource.query(
            {
                TotalItems: $scope.TotalItems,
                ItemsPerPage: $scope.ItemsPerPage,
                PageNo: $scope.CurrentPage
            });
    };


    $scope.TotalItems = 175;
    $scope.ItemsPerPage = 20;
    $scope.CurrentPage = 1;
    $scope.searchPrograms();
});
```

Json I am sending from the server in respons:

```
{"TotalItems":175,"ItemsPerPage":20,"PageNo":5,"List":[{"Code":"MATH2014","Name":"Name1","Tags":"Tag1,Tag2"},{"Code":"MATH2015","Name":"Name2","Tags":"Tag1,Tag2"}]}
```

The angular $response throws error for above json

But if I do not send "List" array within json and send simple json as follows, everything works fine then:

```
[{"TotalItems":0,"ItemsPerPage":0,"PageNo":0},{"TotalItems":0,"ItemsPerPage":0,"PageNo":0}}]
```

I am new to angular and don't know what exactly I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of doing

`$scope.Programs = ProgramsResource.query(`

Use

`$scope.Programs = ProgramsResource.get(`

`query` function expects the response to be an array, where as `get` expects a object. Since you are returning object use `get`.

The default setting for query function is `isArray:true`. This flag helps angular to de-serialize your response into either object or array. See [resource documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

**Also note:**
When you change default settings for a **query** function like the following, you will encounter this error if you do not define `isArray` as `true`. So always add `isArray: true` when you change the default settings for `query`:

```
var res = $resource('/api/userinfoes/:Id', { Id: "@Id" },
            {
                'query':  {
                        method:'GET',
                        headers: {
                             'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                        },
                        isArray:true}
            });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. very basic mistake.