# Why isn't data rendering on my template from my Angular scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

My angular file looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngResource',    
  'ngRoute',       
])

// Creating our routes
.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/professors', {
        controller : 'ProfessorListController',
        templateUrl : 'static/templates/partials/professor_list.html'
      })
      .when('/professors/:professor_id', {
        controller : 'ProfessorDetailController',
        templateUrl : 'static/templates/partials/professor_detail.html'
      })
      .otherwise({ redirectTo : '/' });
  }
])

// Getting all the professors from the API
.factory('Professor', [
  '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/professors/:id', {
      id: '@id'
    });
  }
])

// Creating a controller containing all the professors
.controller('ProfessorListController', [
  '$scope', 'Professor', function($scope, Professor) {
    return $scope.professor_list = Professor.query();
  }
])

// Creating a controller containing a particular professor
.controller('ProfessorDetailController', [
    '$scope', '$routeParams', 'Professor', 
    function($scope, $routeParams, Professor) {
      return $scope.professor_detail = Professor.query({
        id: $routeParams.professor_id
      });
    }
]);
```

The professor list view works and is rendering data properly. However, when I go to say

> /#/professors/2

its just an empty page with nothing on it. My api seems to be working since if I go to /api/professors/2, it gives me the details of the professors with id=2 as JSON.

My template **professor_detail.html** looks like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="text-center" ng-repeat="prof in professor_detail">
        <h3>{{prof.name}}</h3>
        <p>{{prof.university}}</p>
        <p>{{prof.department}}</p>
        <p>{{prof.overall}}</p>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, in case you are wondering, I can see from my terminal that the app is finding the template (Http status 200) and also getting the data from the API (GET HTTP status 200). So what am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: Alright, when I go to #/professors/2, I get the following error in my browser error console:

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$resource/badcfg?p0=query&p1=array&p2=object&p3=GET&p4=%2Fapi%2Fprofessors%2F2
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:6:421
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-resource.min.js:11:51
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:126:506
$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:141:47
$digest@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:138:145
$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:141:348
g@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:94:145
t@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:98:261
onload@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js:99:298
```

Any idea what this is?

Comment: Could you check if the data returned from the API call is details of the correct professor? You could check this in your browsers developer tools.

Comment: @nipuna777 Check the edited post please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `Professor.query` instead of `Professor.get` as the query function expects an Array as the returned value.

`.query` works in the first request as you are returned with a list(an Array) of professors, but once you return only a single professor object, this function fails.

refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26093452/3156644

Answer (score 1):

Your error log first line https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg?p0=query&p1=array&p2=object&p3=GET&p4=%2Fapi%2Fprofessors%2F2 
Documentation says:

This error occurs when the $resource service expects a response that can be deserialized as an array but receives an object, or vice versa. By default, all resource actions expect objects, except query which expects arrays.