# angular resource - $resource:badcfg

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, resources

My angular throws me

> Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `query`. Expected response to contain an array but got an object

I have no idea why this happens. I have a db with schools, and each schools has a city property. i'm trying to get all the schools in a given city.
On the server, my controller has a function which is supposed to do exactly that:

```
getSchoolByData: function(req, res, next) {
    School.find({city: req.params.reqCity}).exec(function (err, collection) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Could not load desired school: " + err);
        }
        res.send(collection);

    });
}
```

On my client side I have a resource and another controller:
resource:

```
app.factory('SearchSchoolResource', function($resource) {
    var SearchSchoolResource = $resource('/schoolSearchResult/:reqCity', {city: 'reqCity'}, { update: {method: 'PUT', isArray: false}});
    return SearchSchoolResource;
});
```

controller:

```
app.controller('SearchSchoolCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, SearchSchoolResource) {
    $scope.schools = SearchSchoolResource.query({city: $routeParams.reqCity});
});
```

I have no idea which one of these fails to work properly and I have no idea how to check. I'm new to angular and node, and I spent over 72 hours on this, so if someone can tell me how to fix this, it will be amazing!
Other than that I managed to return all the schools, and a single school based on given id just fine, but returning schools based on city fails.

EDIT:

If I just put the name of the city in the find function like

```
... find({city: 'name'}) ...
```

It works, but if I use req.params.reqCity it doesn't. I can't figure out why it doesn't work, it seems like req.params.reqCity is returning something different and not the given city name. Tried just using .ToArray instead of .exec and it doesn't work again. Can't figure out what the req.params.reqCity returns and still can't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041306/error-resourcebadcfg-error-in-resource-configuration-expected-response-to

Comment: I tried it. I might have understood it wrong though. I wrote: http://pastebin.com/KGfST9n4 and it didn't work. It stopped giving me the error, but it showed nothing on the page eighter, I don't think it even started the SearchSchoolCtrl code, as I was trying to print something there, that didn't print. I tried changing the paths in my angular app, and express to _/schoolSearchResult_ from _/schoolSearchResult/:reqCity_ and it didn't work eighter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, it should work. In addition to get i am also adding other operation's syntax.

Service:

```
 app.factory('SchoolService',function($resource){
            return $resource('/schoolSearchResult/:reqCity', 
            {
                reqCity: '@reqCity'
            },
            {
                'update': { method:'PUT' }
            },
            {
                'get': { method: 'GET', isArray: false }
            },
            {
                'delete': { method: 'DELETE'}
            }
        );
        });
```

controller:

```
app.controller('SearchSchoolCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, SchoolService) {
        var schoolService = new SchoolService();
        schoolService.$get({reqCity : $routeParams.reqCity},function(result){
                    $scope.schools = result;
                });
    });
```

Comment: Just tried your code, but for some reason it doesn't appear as it should on the page and when i log the result it gives me an array with the page html http://puu.sh/gq2yC/42b0d09cf4.png

Comment: Did you checked your API, is it returning correct result?

Comment: I have found an error in my routing, so now it doesn't give me the previous result. On the other hand when I use your code it says 'Expected response to contain an object but got an array.', but when i change to my old controller it says 'Expected response to contain an array but got an object.', other than that $scope.schools is a not resolved promise. I checked mongodb for the sintax of find, and it seems right, I tried though removing the parameters in {}, but that changed nothing.