# Expected response to contain an array but got an GET

Tags: arrays, angularjs, get, angularjs-resource

I researched this question everywhere but no solution is working for me.
like this: [Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041306/error-resourcebadcfg-error-in-resource-configuration-expected-response-to)

I am still getting the error of bad configuration. Can someone please help me solve this, thanks.

Factory:

```
    angular.module('lensApp')
       .factory('LensResource', function($resource) {
        return $resource(
            'api/lens',
             null,
             {'query': {method:'GET', isArray: false}}
        );
    });
```

Service:

```
var params = {};
params['id[]'] = [1,2];
LensResource.query(params, function(data) {
    console.log(data);     
 }, function(error) {
       console.log("error");
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is in your factory. You shouldn't pass `null` as second parameter.

In `$resource` `paramDefaults` is optional and it only can be an object. If you will pass null here, angular won't treat is an `paramDefaults`. It will assume that there is no `paramDefaults` and null is an `actions` parameter, and your third parameter will be treated as `options` instead of `actions`. That way, $resource will use default implementation of query, which expects array.

To get it fixed, pass empty object ({}) instead of `null`.