# angular.js 1.4.8 Error: $resource:badcfg. Error present in normal browser but not Incognito

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Upon page load I get the following error from Angular:

```
angular.js:12520 Error: [$resource:badcfg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$resource/badcfg?p0=query&p1=array&p2=object&p3=GET&p4=%2Fapi%2Fprospects%2Factive
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:3807/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
    at k.then.p.$resolved (http://localhost:3807/Scripts/angular/angular-resource.min.js:9:408)
    at http://localhost:3807/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:119:129
    at r.$eval (http://localhost:3807/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:133:313)
    at r.$digest (http://localhost:3807/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:130:412)
    at r.$apply (http://localhost:3807/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:134:78)
    at g (http://localhost:3807/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:87:444)
    at T (http://localhost:3807/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:92:50)
    at XMLHttpRequest.w.onload (http://localhost:3807/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:93:78)
```

I suspect that the error comes from the `query` method that is automatically called below:

```
define(['ngResource'], function () {
    'use strict';
    prospectResource.$inject = ['$resource'];
    return prospectResource;

    function prospectResource($resource) {
        var controllerPath = '/api/prospects/';

        var actions = $resource(controllerPath, {}, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                url: controllerPath + 'active',
                isArray: true,
                Cache: true
            },
            all: {
                method: 'GET',
                url: controllerPath + 'all',
                isArray: true,
            },
            convert: {
                method: 'POST',
                url: controllerPath + 'convert/:prospectId'
            }
        });

        return actions;
    }
});
```

The weird thing is that the error only occurs in non-incognito mode in Chrome and not in Incognito. I then tried to do "Empty cache and hard reload", rebooted Chrome, cleared cookies etc but nothing works. What could be causing this? I'm thinking if it could be some plugin but I tried disabling Ad-blocker etc but I still get the same result. In Incognito everything works fine.

Angular version is 1.4.8

Comment: What is the response of `GET /api/prospects/active`? What happens when you remove `Cache: true`?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041306/error-resourcebadcfg-error-in-resource-configuration-expected-response-to

Comment: @str setting Cache to false does not matter. However when I visit `/api/prospects/active` I'm automatically redirected to the login page non-incognito and in Incognito I get the appropriate array. I'm logged in on both browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was cookie related. In Chrome go to `Settings -> Show advanced settings… -> "Clear browsing data…" -> the beginning of time -> mark everything -> Clear browsing data`. Everything started to work.