# Unable to get query to work in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

I'm quite new to Angular and I'm trying to make a simple application that consumes a REST service and presents the results. 
When I try to use the query command in Angular I get the following error: angular.js:14525 Error: [$resource:badcfg] query which a quick search revealed to be something that's thrown when it gets an object instead of an array.

Angular

```
angular.module('strateGISApp.controllers', [])
.controller('CategoryListController', function($scope, $state, popupService, $window, Category) {
  $scope.categories = [Category.query()]; //fetch all categories.
});
```

frontend

```
<tr ng-repeat="Category in categories">
   <td>{{category.id}}</td>
   <td>{{category.category_name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Furthermore, the json I'm consuming from a nodejs rest service returns two duplicate sets. One name recordsets and one named recordset. Can this have any effect on this?

Edit: as pointed out in comments the solution were to add isArray: false but now my page shows a very large number of records (database only have 4) and seemingly unable to access any of the objects properties.

Edit 2: After further investigation (by writing categories with console.log) it seems that I get HTML back from the rest service. Categories is an array

```
0
:
"<"
1
:
"!"
2
:
"D"
3
:
"O"
4
:
"C"
5
:
"T"
6
:
"Y"
7
:
"P"
8
:
"E"
9
:
" "
10
:
"h"
11
:
"t"
12
:
"m"
13
:
"l"
14
:
">"
15
:
"
"
16
:
"↵"
17
:
"<"
18
:
"h"
```

And so on. Array have 1338 entries in total. Somehow I dont process it correctly is the problem with the service? It is a nodejs server that I did not make.
However when i visit the server url in a browser it shows the json as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: \[$resource:badcfg\] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041306/error-resourcebadcfg-error-in-resource-configuration-expected-response-to)

Comment: have you tried $scope.categories = Category.query(); ?

Comment: @Arjun yes I've tried both with and without the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your `<tr ng-repeat="Category in categories">`

'Category' is what you declared or assigned object to(Category in categories)., but in the below line you are trying to access 'category.id' which is starting with 'lowercase' 'c'.

Can you change 'Category in categories' to 'category in categories' and check it?

Comment: I get the same result both with lower and uppercase.

Comment: But you are probably right it needs to be lower case.